# How to use Bootstrap Toggle in PHP?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, toggle

I have a checkbox that I want to look like http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

And if I have html input field like this: `<input checked data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">`, it really looks like that.

But how I am supposed to use this to post value 1/0 to my PHP script like it was a real checkbox ?

Do I need to add something else in html code, and how to process that in PHP script ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should still function like a regular checkbox. The only difference is how it looks. Something like [this](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html) should work.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to set a value to your input, something like

```
value='1' or value='true'

<input checked data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox" value='1' or value='true' name='mycheckbox' >
```

Since it is a checkbox, if is checked it will go with your additional form data when you submit the form...

Then at your php side you just do something like this

```
isset($_POST['mycheckbox'])
```

and then it means it was checked... you can later capture the value (if you need it for something) or whatever you need to do..

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add a `name` and `value` attributes to your input. The plugin takes care of the rest already for you.

Like this:

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.0/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="submit.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="my_input" checked data-toggle="toggle">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Result in `submit.php`:

```
var_dump($_POST);

/*
array (size=1)
  'my_input' => string 'on' (length=2)
*/
```